# How to move messages in "Social" or "Promotions" into "Primary"

Tags: gmail, gmail-categories

I never remember how to do this. My e-mails are categorised in "Social" or "Promotions". I would like these e-mails to be organized into "Primary".

What is the easiest what to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a suitably modern browser simply drag the message from the message list and drop it on the tab where you'd like it to be organized for the future. (You should be prompted by Gmail whether or not you want future messages from the same sender to be added to the new category tab.)

If your browser doesn't allow for that, or if you want to move multiple conversations at a time, Inbox Categories are also listed with your custom labels in the "Move to" and "Labels" menus. Just check the messages you want to move and use the appropriate option.

More information from [Gmail Support](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/3055016/).

Comment: One more detail to mention: only the "Social", "Promotions", "Updates" and "Forums" tabs appear in the Move To / Labels options. To move a message to "Primary", simply _uncheck_ the other tab label that it is currently in. For example, to move from "Updates" to Primary, uncheck the Updates label under Labels.

Comment: I'll add to the answer as well, that when you drag the message over to another tab it'll ask if you want to do that with future messages from that sender, which you can click "yes" to.