# How to indicate that a particular subscription in the "Updates" tab should always go to "Primary"?

Tags: gmail, gmail-categories

I have a couple subscriptions that I'd always like to see in the Primary tab of gmail, but don't know how to indicate such.

Is it possible, and if so how is it done?

Comment: Probably a duplicate: [How to move messages in “Social” or “Promotions” into “Primary”](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/84110/354)

Comment: Agreed functionally the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply drag-and-drop those conversations to the "Primary" tab. Gmail will ask you if you want future messages from that sender to be categorized the same way.

(If drag-and-drop doesn't work for you, you can use the the "Labels" tool; the inbox categories are at the bottom of the list. I think you just need to uncheck the "Updates" category.)

If that still doesn't seem to work, you can always create a Filter that sorts those messages (based on your criteria) to the "Primary" category.

---

See also:

- [Lifehacker: Everything You Need to Know About Gmail's New, Super-Confusing Layout](http://lifehacker.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-gmails-new-super-co-511765933)
- [Lifewire: How to Move Messages Between Inbox Tabs in Gmail](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-move-messages-between-inbox-tabs-in-gmail-1171983)

Comment: Thanks @ale! I'll add to this that when you drag it over it'll ask if you want to do that with future messages from that sender, which you can click "yes" to.

Comment: Great. I'll add that to my answer. (I couldn't access Gmail from where I am; I went by memory.)